# Untracked and changed files are the same

Tags: git

How can git tell me that something has changed if it's not tracked? And how can it be deleted, when it's discovered as untracked?:

```
$ git status
On branch updated-code-foundation
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/updated-code-foundation' by 16 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    component/portal/src/Joppli/Acl/AclInterface.php
    deleted:    container/php-apache/config/apache/default.conf
    deleted:    container/php-apache/config/php/php.ini

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    component/portal/src/Joppli/Acl/AclInterface.php
    container/php-apache/config/
```

I solve it by `git add .` *( no commit needed... )*

1. **Why is this occurring?**
2. **How can I prevent this from occurring?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** The scenario is as following:

- You have a file which is tracked and was previously committed to repository
- You `git rm` the file
- File is created again

Example:

```
git add myfile
git commit -m "myfile"
git rm myfile
echo test > myfile
git status

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    myfile

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    myfile
```

**2.** I am not sure how to prevent it, as it depends on what are the files.
It could be that the files are auto generated and someone committed them by mistake, and then tried to erase them.

Possibly they belong in `.gitignore`?

Comment: Probably the IDE that does some mumbu jumbo :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also has this situation if you are adding `hunks`.

Add the file with the `-p` flag and split the changes.

You will have it in both the working directory (untracked if it was not added before) and in the staging area with the hunks that you have just added.

As you can see in the image you can split the changed and only add few of them to the staging area.

[image]